# How to get items data or library file link by customization button in list view command extension in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-extensions

[image: how do get data of this selected item by clicking on ShortLink which in left side of Automate in list view command extensions]

How can I get data of this selected item by clicking on `ShortLink` which is at left side of Automate button in list view command bar at the top of the list?

Comment: Check my answer below. Let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the data of selected list item on button click using `onExecute()` method in SPFx List view command set.

**For example**:

```
@override
public onExecute(event: IListViewCommandSetExecuteEventParameters): void {
    //Get selected list item(s)
    let selectedListItems = event.selectedRows;
}
```

If you want the first/single item selected, you can use:

```
@override
public onExecute(event: IListViewCommandSetExecuteEventParameters): void {
    //Get first selected list item
    let selectedListItem = event.selectedRows[0];
}
```

Check this SPFx sample for detailed code and more information: [JustALinkCommandSet.ts](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/blob/main/samples/react-command-direct-link/src/extensions/justALink/JustALinkCommandSet.ts)

Comment: hey how can i call the anormal js function in listview command extensions @ganeshSanap

Comment: Use SPComponentLoader for loading the files. Also, it is better to use Typescript code instead of JavaScript code in SPFx. check this if it helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/add-jqueryui-accordion-to-web-part